# How can I assign enum values to a listbox in .NET 1.1 on the Compact Framework?

Tags: c#, enums, listbox, .net-1.1, opennetcf

From http://weblogs.asp.net/stevewellens/archive/2009/08/19/how-to-fill-a-listbox-dropdownlist-from-an-enum.aspx, I see this example for assigning enum values to a listbox:

```
Array Values = System.Enum.GetValues(EnumType);

foreach (int Value in Values)
{
    string Display = Enum.GetName(EnumType, Value);
    ListItem Item = new ListItem(Display, Value.ToString());
    TheListBox.Items.Add(Item);
}
```

However, in my Windows CE project (.NET 1.1), there is no "System.Enum.GetValues()"; there is "GetUnderlyingType" and "ToObject"...

Is one of those the key to accomplishing this?

### UPDATE

Trying to implement Jon Skeet's code, the "ListItem" declaration fails with "The type or namespace name 'ListItem' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

I am using OpenNETCF. So, VS offers to add "OpenNETCF.Windows.Forms.ListItem" to my using block. But when I do, it then complains on the constructor part of that same line (ListItem item = new ListItem(field.Name, value.ToString());) with: "The best overloaded method match for 'OpenNETCF.Windows.Forms.ListItem.ListItem(string, int)' has some invalid arguments"

The entire handler now is:

```
private void PrinterPickerForm_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    // Got this from Jon Skeet (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17952900/how-can-i-assign-enum-values-to-a-listbox-in-net-1-1)
    Type type = typeof(PrintUtils.BeltPrinterType);
    foreach (FieldInfo field in type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public))
    {
        // Fortunately unboxing to the enum's underlying field type works
        int value = (int) field.GetValue(null);
        ListItem item = new ListItem(field.Name, value.ToString());
        listBoxBeltPrinters.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

### UPDATE 2

This works:

```
private void PrinterPickerForm_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Type type = typeof(PrintUtils.BeltPrinterType);
    foreach (FieldInfo field in type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public))
    {
        string display = field.GetValue(null).ToString();
        listBoxBeltPrinters.Items.Add(display);
    }
}
```

It's true that the enums themselves are not populating the listboxes, just the strings that represent them, but that's okay, because I have to use a kludgy way to assign the value, too:

```
private void listBoxBeltPrinters_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    //Tried to do something more "el[egant,oquent]" but .NET 1.1 seems to be holding me back
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17953173/how-can-i-assign-the-value-selected-in-a-listbox-to-an-enum-var/17953297?noredirect=1#17953297
    string sel = listBoxBeltPrinters.SelectedItem.ToString();
    if (sel == "Zebra QL220")
    {
        PrintUtils.printerChoice = PrintUtils.BeltPrinterType.ZebraQL220;
    }
    else if (sel == "ONiel")
    {
        PrintUtils.printerChoice = PrintUtils.BeltPrinterType.ONiel;
    }
    //else if ( . . .)
}
```

Comment: You should modify your question to make it clearer that it's not just that you require .NET 1.1 - you require the Compact Framework. (Enum.GetValues() was part of .NET 1.0 on the desktop...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a long time since I've used the Compact Framework, but I suspect the simplest approach is just to get the field values - and store them somewhere, of course:

```
Type type = typeof(EnumType);
foreach (FieldInfo field in type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Static |
                                           BindingFlags.Public))
{
    // Fortunately unboxing to the enum's underlying field type works
    int value = (int) field.GetValue(null);
    ListItem item = new ListItem(field.Name, value.ToString());
    TheListBox.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: "It's been a long time since I've used the Compact Framework" Lucky!!! <- Napoleon Dynamite

Answer (score 3):

You can create your own `GetValues` method. From [this blog post](http://thekindofme.wordpress.com/2009/03/19/enumgetvalues-on-net-compact-framework/)

```
private static int[] GetValues(Type enumType)
{
    if (enumType.BaseType == typeof (Enum))
    {
        //get the public static fields (members of the enum)
        var fi = enumType.GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
        //create a new enum array
        var values = new int[fi.Length];
        //populate with the values
        for (var iEnum = 0; iEnum < fi.Length; iEnum++)
        {
            values[iEnum] = (int) fi[iEnum].GetValue(null);
        }
        //return the array
        return values;
    }

    //the type supplied does not derive from enum
    throw new ArgumentException("enumType parameter is not a System.Enum");
}
```