# How can I assign the value selected in a listbox to an enum var?

Tags: c#, enums, listbox, .net-1.1

I want to avoid the kludginess of:

```
private void listBoxBeltPrinters_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    string sel = string listBoxBeltPrinters.SelectedItem.ToString();
    if (sel == "Zebra QL220")
    {
        PrintUtils.printerChoice = PrintUtils.BeltPrinterType.ZebraQL220;
    }
    else if (sel == "ONiel")
    {
        PrintUtils.printerChoice = PrintUtils.BeltPrinterType.ONiel;
    }
    else if ( . . .)
}
```

Is there a way I can more elegantly or eloquently assign to an enum based on a list box selection, something like:

```
PrintUtils.printerChoice = listBoxBeltPrinters.SelectedItem.ToEnum(PrintUtils.BeltPrinterType)?
```

?

Comment: Why can't you directly add `enum object` to ListBox

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Because the Enum.ToString wouldn't correctly render "Zebra QL220"

Comment: You have to compromise any one way, check out my updated solution if that helps, else feel free to ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this

```
Array values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(BeltPrinterType));//If this doesn't help in compact framework try below code
Array values = GetBeltPrinterTypes();//this should work, rest all same
foreach (var item in values)
{
    listbox.Items.Add(item);
}

private static BeltPrinterType[] GetBeltPrinterTypes()
{
    FieldInfo[] fi = typeof(BeltPrinterType).GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
    BeltPrinterType[] values = new BeltPrinterType[fi.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < fi.Length; i++)
    {
        values[i] = (BeltPrinterType)fi[i].GetValue(null);
    }
    return values;
    }

private void listBoxBeltPrinters_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if(!(listBoxBeltPrinters.SelectedItem is BeltPrinterType))
    {
        return;
    }
    PrintUtils.printerChoice = (BeltPrinterType)listBoxBeltPrinters.SelectedItem;
}
```

Comment: You cannot cast string to enum with the example you've made. It returns the error 'Cannot cast expression of type 'string' to type 'BeltPrinterType'

Comment: try my whole sample pls, not just cast!

Comment: Then you are correct, maybe it is better to check if SelectedItem is of type BeltPrinterType to avoid exceptions

Comment: Unfortunately, .NET1.1 does not accept/understand this code. See my sister question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17952900/how-can-i-assign-enum-values-to-a-listbox-in-net-1-1-on-the-compact-framework
Looks like I may have to stick with the kludgy method.

Comment: @MartijnvanPut in CompactFramework `Enum.GetValues` method itself not supported

Comment: Ah i didn't know he was mentioniong CompactFramework. That is correct that it is not supported.

Answer (score 1):

With Enum.Parse you could convert from a string to a Enum.

```
PrintUtils.printerChoice = (PrintUtils.BeltPrinterType)Enum.Parse(typeof(PrintUtils.BeltPrinterType),listBoxeltPrinters.SelectedItem);
```

Also there is method Enum.TryParse which returns a bool indicating if the parse is succeeded.

Comment: this will fail in `"Zebra QL220"` case

Comment: You can remove string empty spaces to avoid that problem.

Comment: @Martijn: Similar to my answer to Sriram, unfortunately this won't compile in .NET 1.1, as Enum did not have a "Parse" method back in them olden thymes.

Comment: According to msdn documentation it does exists in .NET 1.1: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.parse(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: That's odd; it's red, isn't offered as an option by Intellisenseless, and causes a compiler error. Come to think of it, probably because this is not just .NET 1.1 (87 lightyears old), but also CD, and thus a "dumbed-down" version.

Comment: Enum.Parse is only supported in CF from .NET 2.0