# Populating a ComboBox from an enum

Tags: c#, .net, combobox, enums

I have an enum for gender:

```
enum gender
{
    Female,
    Male
}
```

Now, I want to populate a ComboBox using for DisplayMember the value in string of each one of the enums casted to string (in this case "Female" and "Male") 
and then for ValueMember the index of each one of the enums (in this case 0 and 1)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I assign the value selected in a listbox to an enum var?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17953173/how-can-i-assign-the-value-selected-in-a-listbox-to-an-enum-var)

Answer (score 3):

```
    enum gender
    {
        Female,
        Male
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(gender)))
        {
            genderComboBox.Items.Add(value.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    //Define the template for storing the items that should be added to your combobox
    public class ComboboxItem
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }

        public object Value { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Text;
        }
    }
```

Add the items to your `ComboBox` like this:

```
       //Get the items in the proper format
        var items = Enum.GetValues(typeof(gender)).Cast<gender>().Select(i => new ComboboxItem()
        { Text = Enum.GetName(typeof(gender), i), Value = (int)i}).ToArray<ComboboxItem>();
        //Add the items to your combobox (given that it's called comboBox1)
        comboBox1.Items.AddRange(items);
```

Example use case:

```
    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //Example usage: Assuming you have a multiline TextBox named textBox1
        textBox1.Text += String.Format("selected text: {0}, value: {1} \n", ((ComboboxItem)comboBox1.SelectedItem).Text, ((ComboboxItem)comboBox1.SelectedItem).Value);

    }
```